# Python error when adding a add_child in folium

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I have the following script. However, I'm getting an error that points are the data I'm passing to the location parameter. When printing this, I'm getting what location generally receives.

[image]

Here is an example of the txt info: VOLCANX020,NUMBER,NAME,LOCATION,STATUS,ELEV,TYPE,TIMEFRAME,LAT,LON
509.000000000000000,1201-01=,Baker,US-Washington,Historical,3285.000000000000000,Stratovolcanoes,D3,48.7767982,-121.8109970

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

map = folium.Map(location=[38.58, -99.09], zoom_start=4, tiles = "Stamen Terrain")

# Reads the data 
df_volcanos = pd.read_csv('Volcanoes.txt')

fg_volcanoes=folium.FeatureGroup(name="Volcanos Map")
fg_population=folium.FeatureGroup(name='Populations')

for index, data in df_volcanos.head(1).iterrows():
    fg_volcanoes.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=data[['LAT','LON']].values,
                                                    radius=6,
                                                    popup=f"{data['ELEV']} mts",
                                                    fill_color='green' if data['ELEV'] < 1000 else 'orange' if data['ELEV'] < 3000 else 'red', 
                                                    color="grey",
                                                    fill_opacity=1))

map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
map.save('Map2.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My modification is to make the circle marker itself belong to a group and add that group to the map. Also, in the sequential processing of the data frame, I did not use indexes to specify rows, so I used `.loc` to limit the rows. At the same time, I also modified the row specification in the popup.

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[38.58, -99.09], zoom_start=4, tiles="Stamen Terrain")

fg_volcanoes=folium.FeatureGroup(name="Volcanos Map")
fg_population=folium.FeatureGroup(name='Populations')

for index, data in df_volcanos.head(1).iterrows():
    color = 'green' if df_volcanos.loc[index,'ELEV'] < 1000 else 'orange' if df_volcanos.loc[index, 'ELEV'] > 3000 else 'red'
    #fg_volcanoes.add_child(
    folium.CircleMarker(
        location=df_volcanos[['LAT','LON']].values[0].tolist(),
        radius=6,
        popup=f"{df_volcanos.loc[index,'ELEV']} mts",
        fill_color=color,
        color="grey",
        fill_opacity=1
    ).add_to(fg_volcanoes)
    #)
fg_volcanoes.add_to(m)
m.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
#m.save('Map2.html')
m
```

[image]